# Live admob ads stopped showing but test ads are showing perfectly well

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I've really big disaster! My live ads are not showing but test ads are showing perfectly well. I don't exactly know what could have gone wrong. I thought maybe it was an issue of regional serving but I've already waited for 48 hours and this is the third day but there is still no change; the live ads are still not working! I've tested some of my banners ad units with admob sample banner example but still the live ads are not showing. All my accounts: admob, adsense and firebase are active and all the ad units are active too. Could this really be the issue of regional serving?! The only logcat error I'm able to see is:

```
E/Ads: Error waiting for future.
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbcl.get(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbq.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzatq.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzatq.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzats.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:848)
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbu.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:848)
```

I have read somewhere that it can be issue of ads not available for my apps because of reasons like it requires sometime for your live ads to start showing after creating them and regional serving of which I'm doubting them being the cause of my problem due to reasons explained above. 
So, please can you kindly help me in knowing exactly the cause of this issue? You can find one of my simple apps attached and run to see whether live admob ads are being displayed in your region.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just be patient. You should expect to wait 2-3 days ***minimum***. If you are seeing dummy ads you can be confident you have things set up correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Let me be patient then but I'm being uneasy!